# Javascript getdate and edit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var firstDate = new Date();
firstDate .setMonth(firstDate.getMonth() - 3);
```

How can i get above date like below in Javascript or Jquery

**13.02.2015**

It must be dynamic date (according to today) i want to get date and 3 months ago like day.month.year.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var date = new Date(), date2 = new Date();
    var todayDate = date.getDate() + '.' +(date.getMonth() +1 ) + '.' +  date.getFullYear();

    date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth()-3);
    var agoDate = date2.getDate() + '.' +(date2.getMonth() +1) + '.' +  date2.getFullYear();

    console.log(todayDate);
    console.log(agoDate);
```